# How to setup a output variable on AzureDevOps from a npm task to pass it to other tasks?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Currently I'm executing a node.js task on a deploy pipeline on AzureDevops. The node task, internally, generates some data that would be helpful if could be able to output from the node task to a Pipeline variable, in order to use it on other tasks after the node.js task finishes.

Exists a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if its a string you can just print to stdout:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=variableName]variable_content
```

and then you can reuse it later in the pipeline with:

```
$(variableName)
```

Comment: This variable can also be used in custom task execution conditions using
eq(variables.variableName, 'variable_content')